# What about setarg/3 is "extra-logical"?

Tags: prolog

The SWI-prolog docs [heavily recommend against](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setarg/3) using `setarg/3`:

> This predicate may be used for destructive assignment to terms, using them as an extra-logical storage bin. Always try hard to avoid the use of setarg/3 as it is not supported by many Prolog systems and one has to be very careful about unexpected copying as well as unexpected noncopying of terms.

I'm not sure I understand, what is "extra-logical" about `setarg/3`? I understand that things such as cuts and findnsols are extra-logical because they rely on implicit knowledge of the search order Prolog uses, what's so bad about changing an argument of a term?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is easy to see that using `setarg/3` violates the *most basic* declarative properties we expect from predicates.

For example, consider the query:

```
?- T = f(a), T = f(b).
false.
```

Declaratively, we expect that **adding a constraint** (i.e., *goal*) can at most **reduce**, certainly never extend, the set of solutions. Right?

Right??

Well, consider:

```
?- T = f(a), setarg(1, T, b), T = f(b).
T = f(b).
```

So, **adding a constraint has generalized the query**: It previously failed, and now succeeds (*unconditionally*).

In everyday tasks, this is analogous to a situation like:

A: I would like to order a dessert please.
**B: I am sorry, we are out of desserts.**
A: OK, then I would like to order a dessert and a coffee please.
**B: Here you are: A dessert and a coffee.**

Surely most people would find such a conversation, if it were to occur in an actual restaurant, highly unusual.

Hence, `setarg/3` is called an *impure* predicate: Monotonic first-order reasoning cannot be applied to it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation.